# How to use routes in rSocket?

Tags: ws, rsocket, rsocket-js

I get project code from rsocket-js examples and tried to make some routes for one connection (requestStream)

I setted mimeType for my metadata as MESSAGE_RSOCKET_ROUTING (message/x.rsocket.routing.v0)
And what i get...

Invariant Violation: RSocketEncoding: Expected value to be a string, got `��� �some.channel`.

I couldn't find any useful information on how this is implemented in JavaScript

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/eloquent-ully-5x9qmv?file=%2Fserver%2Frsocket-server.js

GitHub:
https://github.com/bourbakiii/vue-rsocket

Where i get examples:
https://github.com/viglucci/rsocket-js-examples  (vue+vite directory)

I tried all combinations to set metadata as  "message/x.rsocket.routing.v0" or just "message/text", but getting error anyway

I'm expecting for someone to tell me what I'm doing wrong and to guide me